# Does Ruby create a copy when referencing an array with its [..] (slice) method?

Tags: arrays, ruby, memory, slice

I want to loop on a slice of an array. I have basically two main options.

```
ar.each_with_index{|e,i|
   next if i < start_ind
   break if i > end_ind
   foo(e)
   #maybe more code...
}
```

Another option, which I think is more elegant, would be to run:

```
ar[start_ind..end_ind].each{|e|
   foo(e)
   #maybe more code...
}
```

My concern is Ruby potentially creating a huge array under the hood and doing a lot of memory allocation. Or is there something "smarter" at play that does not create a copy?

Comment: I do. It's an EDA internal S.W. that handles huge chips' internal data.

Comment: I'm not sure what `EDA` and `S.W.` mean in this context, but have you considered using a relational database?

Comment: "under the hood" is always implementation specific. MRI for example is already smart: it will internally use a _shared array_ with hardly any overhead. Additional memory is only allocated if you attempt to modify one of the arrays. Simply traversing a slice is a very cheap operation.

Comment: @Stefan, I didn't know that. Could you share a source? To understand that something is being mutated and create a copy retrogradely sounds like quite the feat.

Comment: @ndn I thought there was a blog post once, but I can't find it. The shared array details are scattered throughout the source code of [`array.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c). You can test it by creating a huge array in IRB `a = Array.new(1_000_000_000); nil` which takes a while and allocates some memory. Now create a slice via `b = a[5..-5] ; nil`. That returns instantly without additional memory usage. Finally, alter either `a` or `b` to trigger the actual duplication.

Comment: Use a database. Pulling in huge amounts of data has the potential to cripple a running script and possibly the machine it's running on, whereas a DBM is designed to handle huge data sets and search/return queries about them. For non-Rails use I like Sequel, but DataMapper is good. ActiveRecord can be used outside of Rails but because it's rarely used that way it's harder to get documentation for doing so. It's even possible to write Ruby/Perl/Python code that the DBM runs remotely so the data doesn't move across the network until it's been crunched.

Comment: BTW, it almost sounds like an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)". Handling large datasets and processing them is full of dragons and generally we want to take advantage of tools designed to handle them. Doing it wrong can really impact an application, a host, a network, or a company.

Comment: @ndn: "To understand that something is being mutated and create a copy retrogradely sounds like quite the feat." – This called *copy-on-write* and is done all the time. And the implementation is not black magic: make it read-only, and if anyone tries to write to it, catch the error, copy, repeat the operation.

Comment: EDA is Electronic Design Automation, S.W. stands for software. And since we are electronics engineers, a relational database may be a humans' resource allocation (training) that I cannot justify. It's "bad enough as it is" that I need to do anything outside TCL (again, capacity issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a loop of index values... not as elegant as your second solution but economical.

```
(start_ind..end_ind).each do |index|
  foo(ar[index])
  # maybe more code
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to refer to methods' C source code, but it takes a bit of time to read the code. May I help you in this

First: each_index

It's source code in C is tricky, but boils down to something similar to 'each' which looks like

```
VALUE rb_ary_each(VALUE ary) {
    long i;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0, ary_enum_length);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
    rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i));
    }
    return ary;
}
```

It does not create any other array internally by itself. What it effectively does is it simply loops through elements, takes each element and passes it into the block provided (rb_yield part). What's actually inside the block that you provide is a different story.

Second: [...].each

You actually have to notice it is two function calls. The second being 'each' is of little interest to us since it is described above The first function call is '[]'. Logically you expect it to output an subarray as variable, which has to be stored at least temporary.

Let's verify. Source code for C is rather long, but the piece of the greatest importance to you is:

```
VALUE rb_ary_aref(int argc, const VALUE *argv, VALUE ary) {
    // some code 
    if (argc == 2) {
        beg = NUM2LONG(argv[0]);
        len = NUM2LONG(argv[1]);
        if (beg < 0) {
            beg += RARRAY_LEN(ary);
        }
        return rb_ary_subseq(ary, beg, len);
    }
    // some more code 
}
```

It's actually for a function call like ar[start_ind, end_ind] and not ar[start_ind..end_ind]. The difference is immaterial, but this way is easier to understand.

The thing that answers your question is called  "rb_ary_subseq". As you may guess from its name or learn from its source, it actually does create a new array. So it would create a copy under the hood of size equal or less of the array given.

You'd want to consider computational cost of functional calls, but the question is about memory.