# Is my algorithm's time complexity O(n log n)?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, benchmarking

```
def two_sum1?(array, value)
    array.sort! # O(nlogn)
    array.each do |element|
        return true if bsearch(array - [element], value - element) == true
    end
    return false
end

def bsearch(array, value)
    return false if array.empty?
    mid_idx = array.length / 2
    mid_value = array[mid_idx]
    return true if mid_value == value
    mid_value < value ? bsearch(array[0...mid_idx], value) : bsearch(array[mid_idx+1..-1], value)
end
```

I'm trying to create a function that finds two unique numbers in an array such that their sum equals the value in the second argument. I believe my implementation has a time complexity of O(n log n). However, when I run it with another function whose time complexity is also O(n log n), the total time is way different (calculated using the Benchmark gem) using the same input. For my function, it takes about 0.9 seconds. For the other function, it is taking 0.003 seconds. Is there any error in my algorithm analysis? Is my implementation not O(n log n)?

This is the other function:

```
def two_sum2?(arr, target_sum)
  arr = arr.sort
  arr.each_with_index do |el, i|
    match_idx = arr.bsearch_index { |el2| (target_sum - el) <=> el2 }
    return true if match_idx && match_idx != i
  end
  false
end
```

This is what I'm using to test the two functions:

```
arr = [0, 1, 5, 7] + [100] * 10000
puts Benchmark.measure { two_sum1?(arr, 6) }
puts Benchmark.measure { two_sum1?(arr, 8) }
puts Benchmark.measure { two_sum1?(arr, 10) }
puts Benchmark.measure { two_sum2?(arr, 6) }
puts Benchmark.measure { two_sum2?(arr, 8) }
puts Benchmark.measure { two_sum2?(arr, 10) }
```

Comment: Big-O analysis doesn't say *anything* about constant factors (or about real hardware considerations like cache locality, so it might not even be a useful approximation for real life scaling).  But anyway, the thing to test is how your algorithm scales with N, not how it compares to a different one.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have checked how the two algorithm's scale. For smaller inputs (for example if i take out the [100] * 10000 part in the arr variable), the two algorithm's take roughly the same amount of time. But for this large input, they seem to scale differently than I expected, since I assume they have the same time complexity.

Comment: Ok, then maybe your implementation isn't O(N log N) because of implementation details.  I don't know Ruby (I'm just here for the benchmarking tag); maybe slicing arrays is actually making copies by value instead of just taking references?  That could explain doing much more work, making your recursive bsearch not actually log(n).  Or just interpreter overhead dominates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm you have created seems correct in general. Let's try to analyze the complexity of that. You have sorting which should be *O*(*n* log *n*) if implemented correctly. Now, let's assume for a moment that your `bsearch` is implemented correctly (which means it has complexity *O*(log *n*)), then you would get for the whole loop *O*(*n* log *n*). Which would still mean that algorithm is *O*(*n* log *n*).

Now let's go to the implementation of the `bsearch`. As I said, it is generally correct (although you probably should consider changing the part with selecting index if Your array has the odd number of elements), the place where it fails is the array slicing. Whenever you slice an array it is internally iterating over the number of elements from the `start` to `end` given in the slice and copying them to the new array, this breaks the complexity and makes it *O*(*n*) instead of  *O*(log *n*) and thus making the whole algorithm *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>), because of the loop.

Comment: Is it also the case that array - [element] (in bsearch's first argument inside the loop) has a time complexity of O(n)? And this is also causing the algorithm to have a time complexity of O(n^2)?

Comment: Ah, yes that  is a problem too, sorry I have missed that bit. But the algorithm is `O(n^2)` because You are doing Your `bsearch` n times since you are using `each`.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's O(n^2).

`array[0...mid_idx]` (i.e. slicing) every time will create a [new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43522226/does-ruby-create-a-copy-when-referencing-an-array-with-its-slice-method). Therefore, `bsearch` is not log(n), but n.

Also, try to rewrite bsearch from recursive approach to iterative. It works faster. Like [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/).